# Ошибка в ключах компиляции в Linux: library -lss: not found

Tags: unix, map-reduce, c++, компиляция, linux

Решил откомпилировать программу согласно [[Compiling Pipes Programs]](http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR/Compiling+Pipes+Programs) и получил следующую ошибку:

> ld: fatal: library -lss: not found
>   ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to wc-simple collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

Библиотеку libss.a или [libss.so](http://libss.so) линкер не находит в стандартных оглавлениях. Укажите в ключе -L путь к ней.

Например:

```
g++ myprog.c -lss -L/path-to-lib
```

Но скорее всего, libss у Вас попросту не установлена.

Comment: в вышеуказанной статье необходимо использовать ключ -lssl